# C++ How to convert unordered_set<int> to unordered_set<string>

Tags: c++

Is there any efficient way of converting from int to string, other than iterating the entire int set and convert them 1 by 1?

I want to convert from `std::unordered_set<int>` to `std::unordered_set<std::string>`.

Comment: You have to iterate in one way or other, explicit or hidden loop.

Comment: `std::transform` (it is a loop)

Comment: No there is not, how could there be? Each item in the set needs to be converted therefore the set needs to be iterated. There are solutions that mean the iteration is done behind the scenes by library code, but the iteration happens nevertheless.

Comment: Do you basically want to convert each member integer to a string?

Comment: you are basically asking: Can I do X for every element in a container, without doing something for every element in the container. No.

Comment: If you really meant to ask, is there a way to do the conversion without **me** writing the loop, then the answer is yes. You could look at `std::transform` for instance.

Comment: You could avoid the loop by using a range adaptor. But then the transformation happens every time a respective iterator is dereferenced. I don't really get what you are asking.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 why not write an answer instead of commenting? I like to see ```std::transform``` in action

Comment: @newbie I would have to invent an example, hence my answer cannot be any more targeted to this specific quesiton than any documentation one can already find online. I suggest this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform, it has a couple of examples

Comment: A good SO question is one that shows sufficient prior research effort. I think if you [edit] your attempt at doing it 1-by-1 into the question, then that will increase the chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Importantly, *how* do you want to convert your `int`s to `std::string`s?

Comment: Why do you want to convert `std::unordered_set<int>` to `std::unordered_set<std::string>`? The former is a more space and time efficient form of storing the same information.